# Does excluding the `else` affect the performance in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I was looking for an existing answer to this question, and while I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467651/is-there-a-performance-difference-by-excluding-an-else-clause) specifically about C#, this is a compiler-level thing, and so I'd expect Python might differ here.

Look at these two ways of terminating a function. First the one *with* the `else`:

```
if condition:
    return some_val
else:
    return some_other_val
```

Then the one *without* it:

```
if condition:
    return some_val
return some_other_val
```

Logically, the two do precisely the same thing, even if `condition` has side effects. They test `condition`, then return a value.

**Is there a chance that Python 3 optimizes one over the other?**

Comment: Operator `%timeit` in iPython will answer your question better than anybody's guess. (Hint: the statement _without_ `else` seem to be somewhat slower.)

Comment: @DYZ Won't iPython perform differently?

Comment: IPython is an interface to Python. Why would it?

Comment: @DYZ repl's don't always carry out the same compile-time optimizations (interpret-time? It's being compiled to bytecode, so we're probably safe saying compile-time)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to find out is to do both of these many times over in a loop (like 10 million times), time both, and see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if there's an optimization, you can use something like [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) to know for sure. It's difficult to give a hard and fast rule for optimization because each code brings with it different executions. For example, if you are just doing a simple x + y computation, it might give you an infinitesimally small edge not to include it, where a complex method with a variable input could cause the machine to do more work to comprehend what it's supposed to do.

From my understanding, it's considered a best practice to always include an else statement. "[Explicit is better than implicit.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)" Always using an else statement gives a hard rule to the program of what to do in each case, it's easier to read (as your code gets more complex) and it will also help you avoid mistakes as you're going.

For an example of better readability:

```
variable_one = "v1"
variable_two = "v2"
if variable_one.isdigit() == False:
    if variable_one == "a":
        print("The variable is a")
    elif variable_one == "d":
        print("The variable is d")
    if variable_two == "v1":
        pass
if variable_two == "v2":
    print("variable 2 is v2")
```

While still pointlessly stupid, this code improves readability:

```
variable_one = "v1"
variable_two = "v2"
if variable_one.isdigit() == False:
    if variable_one == "a": print("The variable is a")
    elif variable_one == "d": print("The variable is d")
    else: pass

    if variable_two == "v1": pass
    else: print ("this variable was not passed")
else: pass

if variable_two == "v2": print("variable 2 is v2")
else: pass
```